# lemma:A function which has premitive always satisfies Inter mediate value property

Tags: analysis

> **Lemma**: *A function which has a primitive always satisfies Inter mediate value property.*

My piont is,
A discontinious function may also have a primitive . For example, 
$$
F(x)= \begin{cases} 2x\,\sin (1/x)-\cos (1/x)  & x \not=0\\
0                                          & x=0
\end{cases} $$
is dicontinuous having the premitive
$$
  f(x)= \begin{cases} x^2\,\sin (1/x)       & x \not=0\\
      0                            & x=0
\end{cases} $$

This implies a discontinuous function may also satisfies IMVP . Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's true.

Let $g \colon [a,b]\to \mathbf R$ a function with primitive $f$, that is $f' = g$. Let $y \in \mathbf R$ between $g(a)$ and $g(b)$. We will find a $\xi \in [a,b]$ with $g(\xi) = b$.
If $y \in \{g(a), g(b)\}$, we are done by choosing $\xi = a$ or $\xi = b$, so we may suppose that $g(a) < y < g(b)$. Define $h\colon [a,b] \to \mathbf R$ by $h(t) := yt-f(t)$. Then $h$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, with derivative $h'(t) = y - g(t)$. As $h$ is continuous, it attatains its maximal value on $[a,b]$. As $$ h'(a) = y - g(a) > 0 $$
$h(a+\epsilon) > h(a)$ for small $\epsilon > 0$. Hence $a$ is not a maximal points. As 
$$ h'(b) = y - g(b) < 0, $$
$b$ is neither. Hence $h$ attains its maximal value in the interior $(a,b)$, let $\xi \in (a,b)$ denote a maximal point of $h$. As $h$ is differentiable, $h'(\xi) = 0$. That is $g(\xi) = y$.